# Match dict values and add a key to the dict if it matchs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dicts.

```
products = [
  {
    'offer': {
      'name': 'Iphone',
      'sku': '1234'
    }
  },
  {
    'offer': {
      'name': 'Samsung',
      'sku': '5678'
    }
  },
]
```

```
prices = [
  {
    'id': '1234',
    'price': {
      'value': 500,
      'currencyId': 'USD'
    }
  },
  {
    'id': '5678',
    'price': {
      'value': 600,
      'currencyId': 'USD'
    }
  }
]
```

I have to add prices to products with matching them by fields "sku" and "id".
I want to get a new list of dicts

```
[
  {
    'offer': {
      'name': 'Iphone',
      'sku': '1234',
      'value': 500,
      'currencyId': 'USD'
    }
  },
  {
    'offer': {
      'name': 'Samsung',
      'sku': '5678',
      'value': 600,
      'currencyId': 'USD'
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to do this:

```
for product, price in zip(products, prices):
    if product.get("offer", {}).get("sku", {}) == price.get("id", {}):
        product.get("offer", {}).update(price.get("price", {}))
```

but it doesn't works. It updates only 14 products (in the list of 4000 products) and I can't understand why.

Comment: The reason it is not working is, that zip join the two dictionaries at random position. Then you check if the randomly chosen elements match. It is expected that only a few of them will by random chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to first create a mapping dictionary from the `prices` list (where keys are `id`). Then to use this dictionary to create the output:

```py
products = [
    {"offer": {"name": "Iphone", "sku": "1234"}},
    {"offer": {"name": "Samsung", "sku": "5678"}},
]

prices = [
    {"id": "1234", "price": {"value": 500, "currencyId": "USD"}},
    {"id": "5678", "price": {"value": 600, "currencyId": "USD"}},
]

prices_dict = {d["id"]: d["price"] for d in prices}

products = [
    {"offer": {**d["offer"], **prices_dict.get(d["offer"]["sku"], {})}}
    for d in products
]
print(products)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"offer": {"name": "Iphone", "sku": "1234", "value": 500, "currencyId": "USD"}},
    {"offer": {"name": "Samsung", "sku": "5678", "value": 600, "currencyId": "USD"}},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
products = [{'offer': {'name': 'Iphone', 'sku': '1234'}}, {'offer': {'name': 'Samsung', 'sku': '5678'}}]
prices = [{'id': '1234', 'price': {'value': 500, 'currencyId': 'USD'}}, {'id': '5678', 'price': {'value': 600, 'currencyId': 'USD'}}]

price_dict = {price['id']: price['price'] for price in prices}
total = []
for product in products:
    sku = product.get("offer", {}).get("sku")
    if sku in price_dict:
        product.get("offer", {}).update(price_dict[sku])
        total.append(product)
```

Comment: There are about ~4000 products and I have to match them with their prices. Not only 1 product.

Comment: @Irina_Xena Now this should work

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through each list:

```
for offer in products:
    for price in prices:
        if offer['offer']['sku'] == price['id']:
            offer['offer'] = offer['offer'] | price['price']

print(products)
```

Result:

```
[
{'offer': {'name': 'Iphone', 'sku': '1234', 'value': 500, 'currencyId': 'USD'}},
{'offer': {'name': 'Samsung', 'sku': '5678', 'value': 600, 'currencyId': 'USD'}}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first transform `prices` to allow easier quierying:

```py
_prices = {
    price['id']: price['price'] for price in prices
}
```

Now it is easiest to just loop once over `products`, since you are just adding attributes to it:

```py
products = [
    {'offer': product['offer'] | _prices[product['offer']['sku']}
    for product in products
]
```

Note that `|` for dictionaries only works on Python 3.9 and newer. For older versions you could use the `**` notation.